# Firebase query: "where" clause is not working, keep returning all documents

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Fetching member with `id == "1112"` and it is not working

```
var query = this.afs.collection('members', ref => ref.where('id', '==', "1112"))

query.ref.get().then(doc => {
   doc.forEach(postDoc => {
     console.log(postDoc.data());
   });
})
```

[image: Firestore]
[image: Result]

Comment: What isn't working about it? If the query is logging `0`, edit your question to include a screenshot of the data you're querying.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I have update my post..currently using Angular 6 and AngularFire2 ver 5...rc11

Answer (score 1):

normally you define a `ref` that points to either a document or a collection, and you may add a `.where`. You fire `.get` on the ref. 
...Rewrite it to say

`var ref = [whatever SDK/homepath].firestore.collection('members).where('id', '==', "1112");`

then pass that ref to your `.get`. and NOTE you appear to be storing numbers as strings which can negatively impact / throw off queries.

Answer (score 0):

You're taking the query and then ask for its `ref`, which returns the collection that you created the query on. This means that you're calling `get` on the entire collection, which returns alls documents.

To only get the documents matching the conditions in your query, call `get` straight on the query. So:

```
query.get().then(doc => {
  ...
```

Alternatively you can bypass AngularFire2, since it has no benefits in this scenario. That means you end up with:

```
ref.where('id', '==', "1112").get().then(doc => {
  ...
```

Comment: Hi Frank, get() is not function of query : [ts] Property 'get' does not exist on type 'AngularFirestoreCollection<{}>'.

Comment: Try my second example in that case. The only difference is that it doesn't use AngularFire at all, which significantly simplifies this case.

Comment: Thank you! Frank..Finally got it working.    var usersCollectionRef = this.afs.firestore.collection('members').where('id', '==', 1113);
    usersCollectionRef.get().then((doc) => {
      doc.forEach(postDoc => {
        console.log(postDoc.data());
      });
    })